# How do I keep my React code properly formatted in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

In my React App the formatting keeps getting messed up.  I have "Prettier Code-formatter" installed.  However, when I apply it the code will format correctly, then a second later go back to being unformatted.  How can I fix this?  Here's a screen shot of what it looks like.

[image]

Comment: It seems like you have installed multiple formatters. Remove all and just use Prettier

Comment: That was it, thank you.